# Warning in ./libraries/phpseclib/Crypt/Base.php#967

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, phpseclib

Today I have upgrade my phpMyAdmin 4.4.09 to 4.4.14, on my Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago) with PHP Version 5.3.3. My database server is MariaDB 5.5.44. I have copied config.inc.php file from previous installation into the newly unpacked one. When I log on I receive this warning messages:

```
Warning in ./libraries/phpseclib/Crypt/Base.php#967
 openssl_encrypt(): Using an empty Initialization Vector (iv) is potentially insecure and not recommended

Backtrace

./libraries/phpseclib/Crypt/Base.php#967: openssl_encrypt(
string ' g8��)@�� �8��',
string 'aes-256-ecb',
string '52627967f3d249d378f33d2b9b1681e7',
boolean true,
)
./libraries/plugins/auth/AuthenticationCookie.class.php#810: phpseclib\Crypt\Base->decrypt(string 'w(�  �9P���(��')
./libraries/plugins/auth/AuthenticationCookie.class.php#458: AuthenticationCookie->cookieDecrypt(
string 'GncowgnLOVDc0h3HKLkC4g==',
string '52627967f3d249d378f33d2b9b1681e7',
)
./libraries/common.inc.php#869: AuthenticationCookie->authCheck()
./index.php#12: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php
```

-

```
Warning in ./libraries/phpseclib/Crypt/Base.php#967
 openssl_encrypt(): Using an empty Initialization Vector (iv) is potentially insecure and not recommended

Backtrace

./libraries/phpseclib/Crypt/Base.php#967: openssl_encrypt(
string '�만�"Na#���` �~',
string 'aes-256-ecb',
string '2}�)6�k4�yK�вQq1jՁ1��o<6H<�>���N��Lj9�i�$�B\'���c�;kc�C���\'�S�΁��� %yخ�3�s ��c?5�� ��{ϓ~�2��j,��Ϗr�BxF�]���\\�[��#���H�IR\\/cA:W�,E��6U    -���Y�oz�   ��@���;5F�8��9]�ݧ��2]�B����Dy��4Nv]5>���3��Su5}���4 ���<3�]}_՗���,� `hG',
boolean true,
)
./libraries/plugins/auth/AuthenticationCookie.class.php#810: phpseclib\Crypt\Base->decrypt(string '�����2^q3���p�n')
./libraries/plugins/auth/AuthenticationCookie.class.php#492: AuthenticationCookie->cookieDecrypt(
string 'n/u3nKcyXnEzof2TcBmqbg==',
string '2}�)6�k4�yK�вQq1jՁ1��o<6H<�>���N��Lj9�i�$�B\'���c�;kc�C���\'�S�΁��� %yخ�3�s ��c?5�� ��{ϓ~�2��j,��Ϗr�BxF�]���\\�[��#���H�IR\\/cA:W�,E��6U    -���Y�oz�   ��@���;5F�8��9]�ݧ��2]�B����Dy��4Nv]5>���3��Su5}���4 ���<3�]}_՗���,� `hG',
)
./libraries/common.inc.php#869: AuthenticationCookie->authCheck()
./index.php#12: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)
```

-

```
Warning in ./libraries/Response.class.php#370
 json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument

Backtrace

./libraries/Response.class.php#370: json_encode(array)
./libraries/Response.class.php#388: PMA_Response->_ajaxResponse()
PMA_Response::response()
```

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: This patch has been merged in the QA_4_5 branch but maybe it should go to 4.4 also. Could you try it? https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/c1495982ab4e0d4e705eb3f1a751ef5104862df7  but for you it would be at line 794.

Comment: Thanks Marc for your reply, I have modified the file, now the third warning is not longer displayed while the other two (Warning in ./libraries/phpseclib/Crypt/Base.php#967) are still present.

Comment: The fix for the third warning will be part of 4.4.15. Looking for a solution about the other warnings.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with PHP 5.3.29 which is the latest PHP 5.3 release. I take care of testing without an openssl PHP extension; this is your case, right?

Comment: Yes, thanks Marc now I have used a work around with Red Hat Software Collection, I have installed PHP 5.5.21 and the problems are disappeared.

Comment: Thanks sysadmin Glad to know

Answer (score 3):

This is a PHP 5.3.3 bug.

I was able to reproduce the issue on PHP 5.3.3 doing this:

```
openssl_encrypt(str_repeat('.', 16), 'aes-256-ecb', str_repeat('a', 32), true);
```

That gave me a "`Warning: openssl_encrypt(): Using an empty Initialization Vector (iv) is potentially insecure and not recommended`"

Funny thing is that ECB mode doesn't make use of an IV. Regardless, I tried to add one, thusly:

```
openssl_encrypt(str_repeat('.', 16), 'aes-256-ecb', str_repeat('a', 32), true, str_repeat('.', 16));
```

That gave me a "`Warning: openssl_encrypt(): IV passed is 16 bytes long which is longer than the 0 expected by selected cipher, truncating`".

So no matter what you do you get an error when using ECB mode in PHP 5.3.3. I even tried setting that last parameter to `''` and got the first error about using an empty IV.

This is not an issue in PHP 5.3.27.

I'm not going to brute force every version of PHP 5.3.* to see when this was fixed but...  my guess is that it was fixed in 5.3.7 with this changelog entry:

"openssl_encrypt()/openssl_decrypt() truncated keys of variable length ciphers to the OpenSSL default for the algorithm. (Scott)"

That talks about keys and not IVs but it's none-the-less the closest entry I can find in their changelog for the 5.3.* series.

**My recommendation**: do a find replace in phpseclib. Find all `openssl_encrypt` lines and replace them with `@openssl_encrypt`.

Really, you should only need to do it for ECB mode but the instructions I gave you are easier. Might also need to do the same for `openssl_decrypt`. Maybe phpseclib should be doing this, too, but I think idk...  the error suppression operator is generally frowned upon as in fact is PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the @ operator in PHP, now I've discovered a bit more about it.

Answer (score 2):

As already partially mentioned before: This is a bug in PHP 5.3.3 (as shipped in RHEL 6).

The bug itself has been already fixed at upstream, however the fix needs to be backported to PHP 5.3.3 in RHEL 6. A bug report has been filed at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1260315 - but in order to prioritize it properly, a support ticket should be created by the affected Red Hat customer at https://access.redhat.com referring to the Red Hat bug report mentioned before - and stating that this fix is needed (and how many systems are affected).

Comment: Thanks all for the answers, I used a work around; I have installed Red Hat Software Collection and I have configured the php 5.5.21, after the errors are disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this page looking for a solution to the error and are using *aes128* switching it to *aes-256-ecb* as per example from neubert above solved the error issue for me.